# Adding the total count of lookup field in a new column

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I need to get the total count of items in lookup field and then add it to another column, i.e. `CountVal`

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(func, 'SP.js');
    function func() {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("HpList");
    var listItem = list.getItemById(11);   
    context.load(listItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
       function() {
           var lookupVals = listItem.get_item("xyz"); //get multi lookup value (SP.FieldLookupValue[])
           var totalLookupVals = lookupVals.length;
    alert(totalLookupVals);
    var a = totalLookupVals.toString();

    $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('HpList')/Items?$filter=ID eq 11",
            type: "POST",
            data:  JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.HpListListItem' }, 
             'gb3c': a}),
            headers: { 
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: function(data) {       
            alert("Items Inserted!"); 

            },
            error: function(data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
    });
       },
       function(sender,args){
           alert(args.get_message());
       }
    );
```

But it is added as a new item as

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected according to your code. In **JSOM** code you are retrieving an item and In REST API code you are adding an new item.

Instead of adding new item, you have to update existing one. For updating, end point will be

```
url:  _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('HpList')/getItemById(11)"
```

No need to use `$filter=ID eq 11`

Change the header and type

```
   type: "PATCH",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-Http-Method": "PATCH",
        "If-Match": "etag of the item. Use "*" for force update"
    }
```

Item updating code

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('HpList')/getItemById(11)",
    type: "PATCH",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        '__metadata': {
            'type': 'SP.Data.HpListListItem'
        },
        'gb3c': a
    }),
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-Http-Method": "PATCH",
        "If-Match": "*"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Items updated!");

    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
},
function(sender, args) {
    alert(args.get_message());
}
);
```

**Summary of updating item using REST API**

- URL will `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('HpList')/getItemById(ItemId)`
- HTTP method will be `PATCH` or `MERGE`
- Needed to specify item's `etag`. `"*"` can be used for force update.

All these things are discussed in my article.

[CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

Comment: can u pls help me wid the code..

Comment: find the code now

Comment: error:`oldItem.__metadata.etag` is undefined.

Comment: Put `"*"` instead of `oldItem.__metadata.etag`. It is updated in the code

Comment: Did it help you? @vikashkumar

Comment: Yes, this is working..

Comment: @AtishDipongkor, can you help with the full code and deployment process.

Comment: @AtishDipongkor requesting you to update the entire code as the final answer.

Comment: What u mean? I did not get :(. @Jason

Comment: In order to deploy the code on a SharePoint List page, please suggest if I need to just the process. What I`m confused is do I need to a content editor on the sharepoint List page and add the code as showin in answer "Item updating code", do i need to perform any further changes?

Comment: It will be much code and irrelevant to this answer. sorry :(